# auto.arima not reading csv file dates correctly (Full Code + Dataset)

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

Here is a full code + dataset

1. r code https://drive.google.com/file/d/16UOuY9HaeGFmNn7POl0Z8vjIxP70xUSv/view?usp=sharing
   and
2. NASDAQ 100 daily prices dataset https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XXNOdWFwY_RqZ1vXmyO5Wj-o4Nu6ci1l/view?usp=sharing

"auto.arima" function simply refuses to read dates correctly.

Can you please take a look. So far, nothing I found on StackOverflow / Google / YouTube worked. Perhaps I am doing something wrong?

I just want to get this working to play around with forecasts (which in most cases aren't accurate at all, but I am doing it for fun).

Thank you! :)

Comment: What's your problem exactly? Is there any error in that code? The `auto.arima` function doesn't actually "read dates". I wonder if you're reading in the data file correctly. You've said it is a csv file but the code has `read_excel`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Ideally your code would be in the post. Please take a look at making a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and further tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

This has got nothing to do with `auto.arima()`. You are using `ts` objects which do not store dates explicitly; instead they store the starting time, ending time and the frequency (the number of observations per time period). The forecast package is designed to handle `ts` objects.

Since you are using `tidyverse` already, you will probably find it easier to use the newer `tsibble` class of objects which stores dates explicitly. Here is the same analysis you posted but done using `tsibble` objects.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
library(feasts)
#> Loading required package: fabletools
library(fable)

NDX_prices <- read_csv("~/Downloads/NDX.csv") %>%
  mutate(trading_day = row_number()) %>%
  as_tsibble(index=trading_day) 
#> Parsed with column specification:
#> cols(
#>   Date = col_date(format = ""),
#>   Close = col_double()
#> )

NDX_prices %>%
  autoplot(Close) + 
  ggtitle("NASDAQ 100 ARIMA") + ylab("Closing Prices")
```

[image]

```r
fit_ARIMA <- NDX_prices %>%
  model(arima = ARIMA(Close))

fit_ARIMA %>% report()
#> Series: Close 
#> Model: ARIMA(1,1,0) 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>           ar1
#>       -0.3767
#> s.e.   0.0583
#> 
#> sigma^2 estimated as 25768:  log likelihood=-1630.42
#> AIC=3264.83   AICc=3264.88   BIC=3271.88

fit_ARIMA %>% gg_tsresiduals()
```

[image]

```r
fcast <- fit_ARIMA %>% forecast(h = 1)

fcast
#> # A fable: 1 x 4 [1]
#> # Key:     .model [1]
#>   .model trading_day           Close  .mean
#>   <chr>        <dbl>          <dist>  <dbl>
#> 1 arima          253 N(10318, 25768) 10318.

fcast %>% autoplot(NDX_prices)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Notes:

- Your data is a csv file, not an excel file, so you can't use `read_excel`. Instead use `read_csv`.
- Because trading does not happen every day, you need to index the series by `trading_day` (number of trading days since the start of the series) rather than `Date`. Otherwise the series will contain a lot of missing values.
- Similarly, the forecasts are indexed by trading day, not date. But these can be translated back to dates if you know what days will be traded in the future.

Comment: Thank you Rob! Now I get it! Thanks a lot man, I am a rookie, and learning every day. You explained everything clearly, and now I get it. You expanded my brain!